# Getting correct subnet_id from Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I'm trying to retrieve AWS subnet_id by passing vpc_id as variable to the playbook and getting a rather strange output.
The related tasks from the playbook:

```
- name:                       Get VPC ID
  ec2_vpc_net_facts:
    region:                   "{{ region }}"
    filters:
      "tag:Name":             tgs_vpc
  register:                   vpc

- name:                       Get Subnet ID
  ec2_vpc_subnet_facts:
    region:                   "{{ region }}"
    filters:
      vpc-id:                 "{{ item.id }}"
      availabilityZone:       "{{ ec2.instances[0].placement.availability_zone }}"
      "tag:Name":             "tgs_public_1*"
  with_items:
    - "{{ vpc.vpcs }}"
  register:                   subnet
- name:                       Get Subnet data
  debug:
    var=subnet
```

I expected to get the subnet ID in this case, however, the output is something else completely:

```
TASK [Get Subnet data] *********************************************************

ok: [localhost] => {
"subnet": {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "aws_access_key": null,
                    "aws_secret_key": null,
                    "ec2_url": null,
                    "filters": {
                        "availabilityZone": "eu-central-1b",
                        "tag:Name": "tgs_public_1*",
                        "vpc-id": "vpc-500c743b"
                    },
                    "profile": null,
                    "region": "eu-central-1",
                    "security_token": null,
                    "subnet_ids": [],
                    "validate_certs": true
                }
            },
            "item": {
                "cidr_block": "172.10.0.0/24",
                "cidr_block_association_set": [
                    {
                        "association_id": "vpc-cidr-assoc-dd6527b5",
                        "cidr_block": "172.10.0.0/24",
                        "cidr_block_state": {
                            "state": "associated"
                        }
                    }
```

Now, I can see from debug that the variable was correctly injected into the filters, but the actual result were simply the json data of the VPC instead of the subnet.

Just make sure that I'm doing it correctly, I've executed the same task with the vpc-id instead of the variable and it was resulted as expected with the subnet details.

What is wrong here in my code?

Comment: Hi @techraf :)
Since I did registered the variables and used the with_items, it's not clear what am I missing here.
Can you kindly explain me what and how I should correct it?
Thank you

Comment: Why do you think you are missing something?

Comment: well, from my understanding (although newbie), if the output shows that the variable was indeed correct and passed the value using with_items, so it should behave the same as I used different approach and states:
{{ vpc.vpcs[0].vpc_id }} - which worked for me.. 
so what it the difference between stating the var and returning the var with_items?

Comment: I don't see anything provingthat  something went wrong in your question. You posted a cut-off `subnet.results` and it looks like it should. The answer under the dup-target explains that.

Comment: Got it, found the issue, thanks